# Leaving an LED on after a serial command

Tags: arduino, pyserial

Trying to run arduino code through pyserial,

Trying to run a code which communicates to the arduino to turn an LED on/off and stays in that HIGH/LOW state until otherwise communicated via the serial port again

the problem I am having is as soon as the python code has run the LED turns off and I can't figure out why its doing this.. any help would be much appreciated.

### Arduino CODE

```
int data;
int EM=13;
#define ever
void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600);                               //initialize serial COM at 9600 baudrate
  pinMode(EM, OUTPUT);                    //declare the LED pin (13) as output
  digitalWrite (EM, LOW);                     //Turn OFF the Led in the beginning
  Serial.println("Actuating Electromagnet");
}

void loop() {
if (Serial.available()>0)    //whatever the data that is coming in serially and assigning the value to the variable “data”
  { 
  data = Serial.read();
  Serial.println(data);
  }
if (data == '1')
digitalWrite (EM, HIGH);                  //Turn On the Led
else if (data == '0')
digitalWrite (EM, LOW);                  //Turn OFF the Led
```

### PYTHON SCRIPT

```
import serial                                                              
import time                                                                   
ArduinoUnoSerial = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem1411',9600)    
time.sleep(2)                                                   
print ArduinoUnoSerial.readline()                     
ArduinoUnoSerial.write('1')
```

Comment: There is nothing in the shown Arduino code that would cause pin `EM` to be set low unless it receives a `'0'`. There is nothing in the shown python script that would send a `'0'`. The problem must be in the code that you haven't shown. Please read [example]. Actually read it.

Comment: You have omitted something from the bottom of the Arduino code - a closing curly brace at least - and maybe more? You seem to be using Python 2 which has been End-of-Lifed for nearly a year - please consider starting your new project on the right track with Python 3.

Comment: What does the line Serial.println(data); say when you send a '1' to the Arduino?

Comment: @JohnFilleau - apologies just a copy paste error, the only thing missing off the arduino code is a closing curly brace.

Comment: @ocrdu -  Serial.println(data) when read back into python is 49

Comment: I was just curious because Serial.read() returns an int and you compare that value to a char.

Comment: I didn't even think of asking what your schematic looks like. Can you show how you connect your LED to pin 13 please?

Comment: `49` is the integral value of the character `'1'` in ASCII code.

Comment: have you tried using char variable, `char data[10];`

Comment: @Ekky why would OP use an array instead of a single `char`?

Comment: My best guess in the absence of a schematic is that pin 13 is connected to the low side of your LED, and the high side of the LED is connected to permanent Vcc. That means the LED will turn on when pin 13 is set LOW, now when it's set HIGH.

Comment: @JohnFilleau im sorry, its my habit when using serial com in arduino, storing data in char array then compare using `!strcmp()`. not the best practice tho. but i agree with you about the wiring.